# Can someone explain how this works?

Tags: c

```
void print(int x)
{
    if (x--)
        print(x / 26), putchar((x % 26) + 'A');
}
```

This is part of a code. I don't understand what the comma after print(x / 26) does.
And when x=55 it prints *BC*.

Comment: Comma acts as sequence point. First print(x/26) will be called and after returning from that call putchar will be called.  In case of x=55, x--  is not zero it first calls print(2).  print(2)  x-- is not zero it calls print(0) .   putchar(1%26+'A')  and putchar(54%26+'A') gives BC output.

Comment: The recursion goes `print(55); print(2); print(0);`

Comment: It is valid C, but the author should be scrutinised.